# Radiogroup checkChangedListerner is not called in dynamic RadioGroup android

Tags: android

I am working with dynamic `RadioGroup` and I want to call `RadioButton` on every click.
I am using `OnCheckedChangedListener` in the for loop where I am initialising all the `RadioGroup`. Can anybody tell me what is the right approch for calling RadioButtons in dynamic `RadioGroup`. Thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i < radioGroupSizeList.size(); i++) {
  final RadioGroup radioGroup = radioGroupSizeList.get(i);
  final int radioGroupId = radioGroupSizeList.get(i).getId();

  radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
          if (group.getId() == radioGroupId) {
              int rb = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

              List<RadioButton> radioButtonsList = radioMap.get(radioGroupId);
              for (int k = 0; k < radioButtonsList.size(); k++) {
                  RadioButton radioButton = radioButtonsList.get(k);

                  String getTextRadio = radioButton.getText().toString();
                  int radioButtonId = radioButtonsList.get(k).getId();
                  if (rb == radioButtonId) {
                      sizeList = allSizesVariations.get(radioGroupId);
                      for (int i = 0; i < sizeList.size(); i++) {
                          String size = sizeList.get(i).getName();

                          TextView textView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(i);
                          textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
                          if (getTextRadio.equalsIgnoreCase(size)) {
                              size_attribute_id = sizeList.get(i).getId();
                              TextView textView1 = (TextView) group.getChildAt(i);
                              textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                              GeneralFunctions.showToast(DetailActivity.this, String.valueOf(size_attribute_id));

                          }

                      }

                  }
              }
          }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: add your code, please

Comment: @SurajVaishnav I edited the code .Please check

Comment: You should move your setOnCheckedChangeListener code outside of for loop

Answer (score 0):

Is this meant as a Preference? if so, I would recommend using the Preferences-API with onSharedPreferenceChangeListener.. In this way, you can check if the key is equal to the key set for the specific Radio view in question, and even what it's value is, and carry out your code as needed.. In fact even without it being an actual Preference, you could still utilize this to achieve a solution.